# How to use same models for test and development/production when there are some missing features in sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have flask-sqlalchemy application

- For development and production I want to use `mysql`
- For testing I want to use `sqlite`.

In the project's models.py I have the following class:

```py
....
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
....
db = SQLAlchemy()
....
class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'posts'
    __table_args__ = {'mysql_engine': 'InnoDB', 'mysql_charset': 'utf8', 'mysql_collate': 'utf8_general_ci'}

    id = db.Column(db.INTEGER, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    body = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    creation_date = db.Column(db.DATETIME, server_default=db.text("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"))
    update_date = db.Column(db.DATETIME, server_default=db.text('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'))
....
```

This model works totally fine under development (when connecting to mysql db), however, when I try to run the tests (connecting to mysqlite db) I get the following exception

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) near "ON": syntax error [SQL: '\nCREATE TABLE posts (\n\tid INTEGER NOT NULL, \n\ttitle TEXT NOT NULL, \n\tbody TEXT NOT NULL,\n\tcreation_date DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, \n\tupdate_date DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, \n)'] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)\n
```

It is complaining about "ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" in the update_date field. I have tried removing this part from `models.py` and the tests worked fine, so this must be the problem.

Is there a way to keep using sqlite for testing and avoid this kind of problems?

Comment: Usually naunces like this are found when migrating code which was written for SQLite to another db like mysql or postgres.  Trying to fix this error would mean making your code SQLite compatible for the sake of testing.  I'd aim to test against mysql, if your dev/prod env is mysql.

Comment: Either limit your code base to a common subset of features, or use the actual target DB for testing as well – or mock your entire DB layer away.